# how to extend UIToolbar to other objects like safari

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, uiview, uitoolbar

Im trying to achieve the effect like Safari on Mac and iPad have with tabbing, With the navigation bar and the current tab are one. How can i extent the UINavigationBar/UIToolbar to merge with a UIView subclass to look as 1?

---

Answer:

I Created my own UIToolbar subclass, and used the `drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method to make the UIToolbar the same color as my UIView subclass that is only that color.

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    //// General Declarations
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //// Color Declarations
    UIColor* gradientColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.916 green: 0.916 blue: 0.916 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* gradientColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.811 green: 0.811 blue: 0.811 alpha: 1];

    //// Gradient Declarations
    NSArray* gradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               (id)gradientColor.CGColor,
                               (id)gradientColor2.CGColor, nil];
    CGFloat gradientLocations[] = {0, 1};
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)gradientColors, gradientLocations);

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(-1, 0, 769, 45)];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [rectanglePath addClip];
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(383.5, -0), CGPointMake(383.5, 45), 0);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);


    //// Cleanup
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Created my own UIToolbar subclass, and used the drawRect:(CGRect)rect method to make the UIToolbar the same color as my UIView subclass that is only that color.

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    //// General Declarations
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //// Color Declarations
    UIColor* gradientColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.916 green: 0.916 blue: 0.916 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* gradientColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.811 green: 0.811 blue: 0.811 alpha: 1];

    //// Gradient Declarations
    NSArray* gradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               (id)gradientColor.CGColor,
                               (id)gradientColor2.CGColor, nil];
    CGFloat gradientLocations[] = {0, 1};
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)gradientColors, gradientLocations);

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(-1, 0, 769, 45)];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [rectanglePath addClip];
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(383.5, -0), CGPointMake(383.5, 45), 0);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);


    //// Cleanup
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom control with custom appearance. Use UIImageViews with stretchable UIImages and recreate the GUI in PNG images. Or use Core Graphics to render the tabs' appearance. ([PaintCode](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.paintcodeapp.com%2F&ei=RsErUKH5EIXc4QTo8YDwBA&usg=AFQjCNGsKi1YIN-n1uzAUIt2WJpdCKNCjA&sig2=31KkdKOuobvJlhoogyeplQ) might help with that).

Comment: yes i own paint code, i made the tabs that way with stretchable images and so it can make tabs any size. im not so good though, and how would i make it myself? because they also have uibarbuttonitems so i would have to code that to add the same way wouldn't i?

Comment: Just put your tab bar below the navigation bar with the buttons.

Comment: i have the tabs already:P so thats done, just need to know how to merge it then with the same color, i tried color picking tools and overlapping it and using the color, doesnt look the same

Comment: Post a screenshot. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: in safari on mac and ipad theres a toolbar/navigation bar, then the tab objects are joined in with it, so if its red, the current tab would be red to and such. how do i get my tabs(can be UIViews, right now UIButtons) to join the toolbar so the color keeps going and it looks like 1

Comment: [Observe](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i) the toolbar's tintColor property. Then redraw your tabs if needed with the same color.